# Update HTML feed posts without refreshing page with Python, Flask and Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm developing a web application that takes input from a HTML form and creates a post so then I display every post inside an article on my landing page. I want to refresh the article posts asynchronously and all I can see is AJAX but I'm not displaying the data with Javascript, I'm doing so with Flask and Python. Basically on my endpoint I execute a Mysql query to retrieve all the data and then send it to a Jinja template.

Here's the code:

```
@app.route('/landing')
def landing():
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM lost_pets')
    articulos_lost = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM found_pets')
    articulos_found = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('index.html', articulos_lost=articulos_lost, articulos_found=articulos_found)
```

I have two different forms that save data into two different Mysql tables, I display all the data from both tables into the same template.

```
<article>
    {% for elem in articulos_lost %}
    <div class="pet pet_lost">
        <h1>Perdido</h1>
        <p>¡Se busca a <b>{{ elem['nombre'] }}</b>! Perdido/a desde el día {{ elem['fecha'] }}
            última vez visto en las inmediaciones de {{ elem['calle_1'] }} y
            {{ elem['calle_2'] }} barrio {{ elem['barrio'] }} a las {{ elem['hora'] }}
            horas.
            Si lo viste por favor comunícate con Usuario.
        </p>
        <a href="/{{ elem['id'] }}" target="_blank">
            <img src="{{ elem['foto'] }}" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for elem in articulos_found %}
    <div class="pet pet_found">
        <h1>Encontrado</h1>
        <p>¡Se busca a <b>{{ elem['nombre'] }}</b>! Perdido/a desde el día {{ elem['fecha'] }}
            última vez visto en las inmediaciones de {{ elem['calle_1'] }} y
            {{ elem['calle_2'] }} barrio {{ elem['barrio'] }} a las {{ elem['hora'] }}
            horas.
            Si lo viste por favor comunícate con Usuario.
        </p>
        <a href="/{{ elem['id'] }}" target="_blank">
            <img src="{{ elem['foto'] }}" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</article>
```

What's the easiest way of refreshing the content of the article as the users insert new data without having to refresh the page?

Comment: I'd say you need JS to update your page without refreshing. Flask is server-side and cannot control browser like that.

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating an endpoint which returns all my data in JSON so then I can fetch that endpoint with AJAX and populate the page. Thank you.